# Android wear - WatchViewStub deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I am trying to build an Android Wear app. When I start new project with APK 23 (Marshmallow) and above, the default code I get with the new project are as follows;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub)
            {
                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But according to a [Android blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/build-beautifully-for-android-wear.html), `WatchViewStub` class is deprecated from API 23 (Marshmallow). According to the blog files `rect_activity_main.xml` and `round_activity_main.xml` are replaced by one layout file. But my problem is even when I start a new project with newer APIs I still get the deprecated classes and files  (XMLs) in  my project. According to the blog, this is how the new default code should look like in `main_activity.java`;

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {  
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
     mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);    
 }
```

How do I fix this? Please comment before down voting. I have tried a lot of things around the web; Asking at stack overflow was my last resort.

Comment: What version of Android studio do you use? Maybe you should update to the latest stable version

Comment: You can also check this [blog](https://sterlingudell.wordpress.com/category/wearables/), this provides a workaround to the deprecated WatchViewStub. You can use [`onApplyWindowInsets`](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/issues.html#ScreenShape), which can easily get the screen shape there – and inflate the proper layout accordingly. There is also an official blog post regarding [Build beautifully for Android Wear’s Round Screen using API 23’s -round identifier](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/04/build-beautifully-for-android-wear.html). Hope this helps

Comment: @VadimKotov I use Android Studio 2.3.1

Comment: @Mr.Rebot Thats the same blog I referred to in my question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using one of Android studio's skeleton projects. Then amend the code as needed. I am not still sure how to do this by default when we open a new project.